# ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle9i

when I am trying to create datafile as

```
alter tablespace table_data add datafile '/oracle/u07/USPRD71/USPRD71_table_data_02.dbf' size 11G;
```

this is giving me  an error 
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Comment: There is nothing wrong in the syntax

Answer (score 0):

The cause for this error is you have tried to execute a SQL statement with an inappropriate clause.
This would help you to fix the syntax error.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_3002.htm#SQLRF01002